# Trim numbers at beginning and at the end

Tags: sql, string, oracle, trim

I have the following ID number format

```
70800123467
```

The ID I need requires me to remove `708` from the beginning and `67` from the end, leaving me with 001234.

Comment: By which programming language? Is the start always be 708, or you want to remove first 3 digits whatever they are. And more... Please improve your question.

Comment: Given the username we could guess SQL but then we still need to know which RDBMS it is so please tag your question with either a programming language or `sql` and the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`SUBSTR`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_2101.htm#OLADM679) for Oracle databases:

```sql
SUBSTR('70800123467', 4, 8) -- remove first 3 chars from a string with length of 11
SUBSTR('70800123467', -3, 8) -- remove last 2 chars from a string with length of 11
```

So, propertly nesting those two:

```sql
SUBSTR(SUBSTR('70800123467', 4, 8), -3, 6)
```

would return `001234` as you wish.